# Connecting from localhost to cloud database I get this error

Tags: php, mysqli

When I connect from localhost I get this error

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\vici\index.php on line 9
>   Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

here is my code

```
$servername = "27.111.132.11";
$username = "root";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: can you ping that IP?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to connect to the correct IP?

Comment: sometimes it happens to me too.. I just restart both apache and mysql and the magic happens

Comment: @ Brent Lobbezoo yes correct ip

Comment: @ delboy1978uk yes i can ping

Comment: do you have nmap? nmap the IP and see if the port is opened. If not you might need to connect through an SSH tunnel

Comment: ah, you don't, you're on Windows. See if you can somehow port scan the IP and see which ports are exposed

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connection driver does not get any meaningful server at the location of localhost. So use,

```
'hostname' => '127.0.0.1'
```

rather than

```
'hostname' => 'localhost'
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like he's trying to connect to a DB on localhost. He's trying to connect from localhost to an external DB.

Comment: @Dodis ,so how can i can connect with " 27.111.132.11"  this server ,can you explain it